# How to use declare -x in bash

Tags: bash, shell

Can some one give an example where `declare -x` would be useful ?

Answer (score 10):

Use `declare -x` when you want to pass a variable to a different program, but don't want the variable to be used in global scope of the parent shell (i.e. when declaring inside a function).

From the bash help:

> When used in a function, `declare` makes NAMEs local, as with the `local`
> command.  The `-g` option suppresses this behavior.

> -x        to make NAMEs export

> Using `+` instead of `-` turns off the given attribute.

So `declare -gx NAME=X` will effectively behave the same as `export NAME=X`, but `declare -x` does not when the declare statements are inside functions.

Answer (score 9):

`declare -x FOO` is the same as `export FOO`. It "exports" the `FOO` variable as an environment variable, so that programs you run from that shell session would see it.

Comment: I don't think they are exact synonyms.

Comment: No? Then why is it that when you run `export` (without any arguments), it prints out the current exports using `declare -x`?

Comment: I'm not sure, but see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7506644/834176). I tried it and they act differently.

Comment: Downvoted, because this answer contains a false statement. `declare -x FOO` is **not** the same as `export FOO`. In particular, the former will not affect the global scope from within a function, whereas the latter will. `declare -gx FOO` might be the same as `export FOO`.

Comment: @user82116 is correct and this answer should be changed to -gx.  I was trying just -x in a function and it exported only within the function  but did not export even though there was no subshell.  -gx worked.  Note using "export" within a function works as expected

Answer (score 8):

Declare -x can be used instead of eval to allow variables to be set as arguments to the shell.  For example, you can replace the extremely insecure:

```
# THIS IS NOT SAFE
while test $# -gt 0; do
  eval export $1
  shift
done
```

with the safer:

```
while test $# -gt 0; do
  declare -x $1
  shift
done
```

As an aside, this construct allows the user to invoke the script as:

```
$ ./test-script foo=bar
```

rather than the more idiomatic (but confusing to some):

```
$ foo=bar ./test-script
```

Comment: Thanks. But how is the first option insecure ?

Comment: Anytime you eval a string, you give the user who can construct the string the ability to make the script do anything.

Comment: `set -k` in the calling shell lets you treat any `name=value` pairs to be treated as environment modifications, regardless of whether they appear before or after the command. `declare "$1"` may be sufficient, without `-x`, if you only need to define a variable to use in the current shell, rather than actually exporting it.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted solution is not accurate, as commented by @sampablokuper.
However both export variable `a` to subshells (below within ()).
test.sh:

```
#/bin/bash
foo() {
    declare -x a="OK"
    ([ "$a" = "OK" ]) &&  echo "foo exported a locally"

}

bar() {
    export a="OK"
    ([ "$a" = "OK" ]) && echo "bar exported a locally"
}

foo
echo "Global value of a by foo: ${a}"  
([ "$a" = "OK" ]) &&  echo "foo exported a globally" \
                  || echo 'foo did not export a globally'
bar
echo "Global value of a by bar: ${a}"  
([ "$a" = "OK" ]) && echo "bar exported a globally" \
                  || echo 'bar did not export a globally'
```

Runs as follows:

```
$ ./test.sh
foo exported a locally
Global value of a by foo: 
foo did not export a globally
bar exported a locally
Global value of a by bar: OK
bar exported a globally
```

Comment: Indeed, I was just banging my head until I discovered this. The global subshell doesn't have anything to do with it. Simply doing the following: `function foo { declare -x a="OK"; }; echo $a` we will see that `a` is not printed. But  `function foo { a="OK"; }; echo $a` does print OK (here also the 'export' isn't related. So it seems that 'declare -x' defines a _local_ variable, that is exported and used in further subshells, but it does not persist beyond the _function_ scope of the parent process.

Comment: Thx Jon, I finally get it reading the last sentence of your comment! ♥ Bash definitively has unique subtleties. I wrote many shell scripts as a part of my job for decades, only recently I decided to **really** dive into Bash, what a journey… It is a rather odd language (compared to Python typically), I think this is why I love it. ^^