# Using Declare Inside a Function in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, global-variables

I am want to change a global variable (or at least append to it) using a function.

```
input="Hello"
example=input    

func() {
    declare -x $example="${input} World"
}

func
echo $input
```

The output of this would be "Hello" The original value. I would like it if the function were to able to change the original value.  Is there alternative to accomplishing this. Please note I need to set `example=input` and then perform on the operation on example (the variable).

BTW, if I used `eval` instead the function will complain about World being a function or something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try using export?

```
export $example="${input} World"
```

Answer (score 3):

you should use

```
declare -x -g $example="${input} World"
```

in your `func`

> The -g option forces variables to be created or modified at the global scope, even when declare is executed in a shell function. It is ignored in all other cases.

see

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html

Also note in MinGW, it seems that `declare` does not support the `-g` option.

Comment: you can combine those `declare -gx`   Also `declare -x`  will export but only within the scope of the function.  See related question https://stackoverflow.com/a/5785683/4695378

Answer (score 0):

You could use `eval` by redefining func() as the following:

```
func() {
    eval $example=\"${input} World\"
}
```

This allows the double-quotes to "survive" the first parsing (which expands the variables into their values, as needs to be done) so that eval starts parsing again with the string 'input="Hello World".

As for the use of `export` to do the job, if the variable input does not actually need to be exported, include its '-n' option:

```
export -n $example=...
```

, and the variable remains a shell variable and does not get exported as an environment variable.

Comment: Using `eval` is generally frowned upon, because it opens you to command injection attacks if you have any untrusted user input.

Comment: ... if there is a better way. Bash <v4.3 does not support `declare -g` and if `export` would not work for specific case, eval would be the only option here. In this answer, script could be hacked by `input='ha"; date; "'` but easy fix is to add single quotes: `eval '$example=\"${input} World\"'` and this eval will be safe.