# Export command in Unix

Tags: unix, export

I am new to Unix and I know that the `export` command can be used for creating session variables but what is the purpose of the command below:

```
bash-3.2$ export $TEST
declare -x PWD="/home/username"
declare -x SHELL="/bin/bash"
declare -x SSH_TTY="/dev/pts/4"
declare -x USER="username"
```

Please help me in understanding this command. I don't have any variable with name TEST, but when I gave this command the shell printed some output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use declare -x in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785668/how-to-use-declare-x-in-bash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell expanded the non-existent variable `$TEST` into an empty string, and then ran the command `export` with no arguments.  When you do that, the shell lists the exported environment variables.

If you want to export an empty variable TEST, you should have written any of these:

```
export TEST
export TEST=
export TEST=''
export TEST=""
```

(and in this case, there are other ways to achieve the same effect, such as `export TEST=$TEST` or, more or less sanely, `export TEST="$TEST"`, but that is normally abbreviated to `export TEST`.)

The detailed `declare -x` notation in the output is designed to allow you to take write the output to a file, and then reload the environment with the `.` (dot) or `source` commands.  Different shells present the output differently, and not necessarily reusably.

The `set` command is similar (but more complex).  It can be used to set shell options, to set the positional arguments (`$1`, `$2`, etc), but when run with no arguments it lists the set variables.  Note that not every variable that is created is an exported environment variable.